# Goalseek for several columns

Tags: vba, excel

I want Goalseek to run through several columns ("BB:BP"). Currently it is working with column "BB" only in the following way:

The value in cell "BB63" changes, when the value in cell "BB62" is equal to the value in cell "BB61".

This is the code:

```
Sub Goalseek() 

    With Worksheets("sheet_input")
        .Range("bc62").GoalSeek _
        Goal:=.Range("bc61").Value, _
        ChangingCell:=.Range("bc63")
    End With

End Sub
```

I want to create a loop so that it works all the way to column "BP" when I run a single macro. I came up with the following:

```
Public Sub Goalseek()
  Dim rngCol As Range
  For Each rngCol In ActiveSheet.Range("BB61:BP63")
    rngCol.Cells(54, 62).GoalSeek Goal:=rngCol.Cells(54, 61), ChangingCell:=rngCol.Cells(54, 63)
  Next rngCol
End Sub
```

But it is not working. I get the following error:

> Compile error: Only comments may appear after End Sub, End Function, or End Property

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's just deal with a little code tidying before addressing your error issue.

When you define a `Range`, the `.Cell` object is defined relative to that range. So `.Cell(1, 1)` is actually referencing the first cell in your `Range` (ie "BB61") not the whole `Worksheet`.

So your code might be better as follows:

```
Sub Goalseek() 
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim cell as Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet input").Range("BB62:BP62")
    For Each cell in rng.Cells
        cell.GoalSeek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:= cell.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub
```

Your error is occurring because of code you haven't posted. Somewhere under `End Sub` you will have more code. Most often it results from deleting a previous routine, so you might find you have a bit of old code left at the bottom of your module, typically `End Sub` occurs twice for example.

Comment: Hi Ambie. Thank you for the reply. I forgot about the defined range. It is working now. When I want to "restart" goalseeker, I set the values in row 63 equal to 0. Is there a way to automize this, so before I run the macro all the cell values are set to 0?

Comment: `rng.Offset(1).Value = 0`

Comment: Brilliant. It worked. The last thing I need for this macro to be fully automatic is to adjust the new row, row 64 which depends on row 61 and 62 in the following way: If 'value in cell in row 61' >= 'value in cell in row 62', then 'value in cell in row 64' = 1, otherwise it is equal to -1. This needs to be done before the goalseeking is initialized, otherwise it will be equal to 1 for all columns. The logic is intuitive, but I'm not sure where to insert it.

Comment: I'm thinking something in the lines of: Sub Goalseek()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet_input").Range("BB62:BP62")
        rng.Offset(1).Value = 0
    For Each cell In rng.Cells
        If cell.Value >= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then _
        cell.Offset(2) = 1 Else _
        cell.Offset(2) = -1
        cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
    Next
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my intial question as well as the two additional questions to be:

```
Sub Goalseek()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pb_input").Range("BB62:BP62")
    rng.Offset(1).Value = 0
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then _
    cell.Offset(2) = 1 Else _
    cell.Offset(2) = -1
    cell.Goalseek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to be:

```
Sub GoalSeek()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("pb_input").Range("BB62:BP62")
rng.Offset(1).Value = 0

For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.Value <= cell.Offset(-1).Value Then
        cell.Offset(2) = 1
    Else
        cell.Offset(2) = -1
    End If

    If cell.Offset(-1) > 0 Then
        cell.GoalSeek Goal:=cell.Offset(-1).Value, ChangingCell:=cell.Offset(1)
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```